# Why can I still read compressed files?

Tags: windows, windows-8, compression, zip

Why is it that when I Zip some files in Windows and double click on the resulting file, I can still see all the files in their original form?

Since they were compressed, shouldn’t they be illegible?

Or does Windows temporarily unZip them when I’m looking at them?

**Update:** I think I found the answer.

I double-clicked on one of the images that was compressed, and I got the following message:

> Windows cannot complete the extraction. The destination file could not be created.

So I suppose it is extracting/uncompressing the file. In retrospect, that seems like the obvious answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, compressed archives keep a file and folder table inside so that when viewing an archive, you can choose what you want to extract.  If you try to open one or more files/folders, the compression program will have to uncompress the that data.

Answer (score 1):

You've discovered one of the reasons why zip files are so popular as phish/virus email attachments. Windows has the built in ability to read the contents of a non-password protected zip file just like it was a folder with uncompressed contents.

I shut that function off back when I was running Windows XP.